# Does chipset determine if wifi card will be supported under linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers, network-interface, hardware-compatibility

I'm planning wifi card upgrade and I've decided to look for router targeted hardware because of better specs. I found MikroTik mPCI-E module that features Atheros AR9582. I also found that Linux driver ath9k does support this chipset. Does it mean this card should work under linux despite fact that It's meant for routers? Technically their hardware is as far as I know certified to work with OpenWRT. I'm not sure if OpenWRT uses the same drivers as ordinary linux distributions.

Comment: most likely it is supported. If you have money-back option then just try.

Comment: It works in one laptop but doesn't work in my primary one. PC completely doesn't see PCI-E card I'm not even sure where to start troubleshooting... It's not OS related issue because I've tested with the same live CD on both machines.

Comment: what lspci shows?

Comment: nothing at all. The same output as when there's no card inserted. I'm not even sure how to debug it. `dmesg` doesn't seem to show anything interesting. I've asked about whitelists and Clevo W110ER doesn't have wifi whitelist.

Comment: it looks strange. The lack of any info in dmesg tells that probably even pcie-e link training does not happen